# WinRT C++/CX Tasks not compiling

Tags: windows-runtime, task, c++-cx, ppl, iasyncoperation

I'm trying to use C++/CX to create a WinRT component. I have the following code and it doesn't compile. What is wrong with it?
From what I understand PPL tasks should transparently be converted to IAsyncOperation if it's a task with a result.

```
IAsyncOperation<Boolean>^ Class::OpAsync()
{
    return create_task([] () { return true; });
}
```

**Error Message**

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'Concurrency::task<_ReturnType>' to 'Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<TResult> ^'
          with
          [
              _ReturnType=bool
          ]
          and
          [
              TResult=bool
          ]
          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The create_task() function is for taking an IAsyncOperation and turning it into a task (basically, the reverse of what you're wanting).

To convert a task to an IAsyncOperation, you need to call create_async() instead.